# Code review entire repo on GitHub without new commits

Tags: github

How can I conduct a code review for an interview candidate on GitHub using a PR/code review in the absence of new commits? Can I use a hack like making a fork, or do I need to clone the repo locally and read through line-by-line? I'm particularly interested in the per-line comments.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to checkout his existing work or did you give him a problem to solve?
If it's an existing repo, I would suggest that you clone the repo locally and check it out on an IDE.

You might even use a Linting to make the job quicker!

Comment: Existing work. I'd like to be able to comment on a line to get clarification, which I can't really do in my IDE. Maybe another tool, like Kiln?

Comment: Ah, then maybe another tool like Kiln can help. Also, with the GitHub Universe 2016, they have introduced enhanced reviews.

Answer (score 1):

You *can* make comments on pre-existing commits but not the entire repo as one unless it was committed in one commit. The only way comments are usually allowed on Github is if the comment is "related" to a commit, so then Github knows at which point in the repo's history the comment happened.

My suggestion for you would be to make comments on a commit that contains a lot of changes so that you're not going back and forth between many commits.